# How can I sort an object alphabetically by value?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, object, ecmascript-6

So I have a list of countries, by default they come sort by ISOA2 Code which is some kind of country code.

Say this list:

```json
{
  "AD": "Andorra",
  "AE": "United Arab Emirates",
  "AF": "Afghanistan",
  "AG": "Antigua and Barbuda",
  "AI": "Anguilla",
  "AL": "Albania",
  "AM": "Armenia",
  "AN": "Netherlands Antilles",
  "GB": "United Kingdom"
}
```

And I have this code:

```js
    function sortObject(obj) {
      return Object
        .keys(obj)
        .sort()
        .reduce((a, v) => {
          a[v] = obj[v];
          return a;
        }, {});
    }

    
    // data is the list of countries
    const result = sortObject(data);
```

I am trying to sort it with that code but it always returns the same list.

I need the list to be like this:

```json
{
  "AF": "Afghanistan",
  "AL": "Albania",
  "AD": "Andorra",
  "AI": "Anguilla",
  "AG": "Antigua and Barbuda",
  "AM": "Armenia",
  "AN": "Netherlands Antilles",
  "AE": "United Arab Emirates",
  "GB": "United Kingdom"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

You can play around here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/js-playground-forked-xk005?file=/src/index.js

You will see the result in the console.

Comment: What is "like this"? That looks absolutely random to me.

Comment: Also sorting objects is kinda fun as they're sorted by insertion order, so any change to it messes up the sort. Have you considered an array instead?

Comment: Hey @JonasWilms if you see the second object, it is sorted alphabetically by value, not by key.

Comment: It can not be an array. And it is static object so there won't be insertions of any kind.

Comment: Ah, yeah then `.keys(obj).sort()` is kinda senseless right?

Comment: That is what I tried.

Comment: Do not use objects if you need an order. Use an array.

Comment: @Bergi I didn't set that requirement.

Comment: @Reacting But you can change it, right? Press back, file an issue, make whoever did set it fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for sorting:

```
const sortObject = obj => {
  const ret = {}
  Object.values(obj)
      .sort()
      .forEach(val => {
          const key = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === val)
          ret[key] = val
      })
  return ret
}
```

Comment: This is a) horribly inefficient and b) does not correctly deal with duplicate values

Answer (score 1):

Take the `Object.entries` sort them by value, then use `Object.fromEntries` to turn this array of key-value pairs back into an object:

```
 Object.fromEntries(
   Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(([keyA, valueA], [keyB, valueB]) => valueA.localeCompare(valueB))
  )
```

Note that sorting objects is senseless if there are numeric keys or if the object is mutated (as that changes sort order again).

Comment: With this I get an error: Type '{ [k: string]: unknown; }' is not assignable to type 'string[] | { [key: string]: string; }'.
  Type '{ [k: string]: unknown; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
    'string' index signatures are incompatible.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: I am using Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

Does this works for you?

```js
function sortObject(obj) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object
    .entries(obj)
    .sort((a,b)=>a[1].localeCompare(b[1])));
}

const data = {
  "AD": "Andorra",
  "AE": "United Arab Emirates",
  "AF": "Afghanistan",
  "AG": "Antigua and Barbuda",
  "AI": "Anguilla",
  "AL": "Albania",
  "AM": "Armenia",
  "AN": "Netherlands Antilles",
  "GB": "United Kingdom"
}

// data is the list of countries
const result = sortObject(data);

console.log(result);
```